# Ubuntu 20.04.6 doesn't shutdown properly

Tags: 20.04, bug-reporting

I recently installed Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS and when I go to shut down the computer, the computer doesn't shut down properly, it's just turning off the monitor screen, however the lights are still on. I'm always having to force the computer to turn off the power outlet, because if I don't force the shutdown, I won't be able to turn it back on later. Does anyone have a solution for this problem? Thank you very much in advance for everyone's attention!

Comment: Additional information needs to be added to your question. 1. Did/does it shut down correctly running a different OS? 2. Have all Ubuntu software updates been applied? 3. What is the current Linux version (add result of Terminal command `uname -r`.

Comment: 1. Yes, when I was using Windows 8.1/10 it shut down normally, this started happening after I installed Ubuntu.

2. Yes, I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04. 2 LTS, even with the updated kernel, the error still persists.

3. Current kernel version is version 5.19 (5.19.0-43-generic)

Answer (score 0):

Can anyone help me? I recently updated to Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS, the kernel was also updated to version 5.19 (5.19.0-43-generic), and even so the error still persists, I am not able to solve it.

Comment: Hello, if you want answers you should not ask question in answer section try updating or asking a new question.

Comment: Ok, i'm sorry. Thought I might post the question in the same thread.

Comment: No one is responding in my thread, I really need to solve this problem.